# Does left-to-right evaluation not matter when only the right-most operation is non-commutative?

Tags: notation, associativity

So I've been working on a formula compiler and came across a bug in the order of operations that made

$2 - 2 + 2 = 4$

and have now learned to appreciate order of operations and that subtraction is not commutative.

I found that the same issue occurred with for division, where

$16 / 8 * 2 = 1$

So now I've fixed the issue, and am looking for more test cases.

while I can easily find them of the form

$a ÷ b * c$

where evaluation left-to-right differs from right-to-left, I cannot seem to find an example where

$a * b ÷ c$

is sensitive ltr vs rtl evaluation... likewise for subtraction!

So, I'm starting to suspect that if the operator have the same precedence, then

$a (commutativeop) b (noncommutativeop) c$

is not sensitive to ltr vs rtl, but that

$a (noncommutativeop) b (commutativeop) c$

is.

Have I encountered something fundamental going on here, or am I bad at looking for examples, or is this just a coincidence with division and subtraction?

---

**PS** please add appropriate tags

Comment: The title seems to ask about the *right-most* operation being non-commutative, but your first two examples involve commutation operations on the right end of the expressions.

Comment: Tweaked the title, but yes, it seems like it's only an issue when its on the left, since I can't find examples when it is on the right.

Comment: If one of your operations was called *difference*  defined as $x ? y = |x-y|$, then it would be commutative but not associative for example with $1 ? (2 ? 3) = 0$ while $(1 ? 2) ? 3 = 2$

Comment: Parentheses will help make clear what ordering the operations means.  Of course one needs more than simply the commutative or noncommutative character of operations to show the order "doesn't make a difference".  For example, $(a+b)÷ c$ is not generally equal to $a+(b÷ c)$.

Comment: @hardmath + and ÷ have different precedence so that is more obvious that it matters (would violate BEDMAS etc), but I'm asking about ltr vs rtl within a precendence

Comment: Your mention of "BEDMAS" would indicate division and multiplication also have different "precedence".  Precedence is not mentioned until the very end of the body of your Question.  Rather you explicitly introduce left-to-right vs. right-to-left evaluation (something supported by some programming languages with regard to precedence). The form of your Question is not especially about "commutativity" (which involves changing the order of *operands*) but rather about "associativity" (order of evaluation involving the same operation).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** in response to comment.

I misread the question. Original answer below. New discussion, not really an answer to your question. But it may help.

Operator precedence is subtle, and about associativity, not commutativity. The correct mathematical way to think about subtraction is in terms of the additive inverse - that would be the "unary $-$" operator in a computer language. Then
$$
a - b + c \quad \text{ is really } \quad a + (-b) + c .
$$
Precedence binds the unary $-$ more tightly than $+$. After you've invoked it you have commutative and associative addition.

---

I think your problem is really about order of operations and hence associativity, not about which operations commute. For example
$$
"a\times b-c": (a \times b) -c \ne a \times (b-c)
$$
and
$$
"a - b \times c": (a - b) \times c \ne a - ( b \times c)
$$
It doesn't matter whether the noncommutative subtraction is first or second.

Comment: multiplication and subtraction are different levels of precedence within BEDMAS/PEDMAS etc, I'm asking about when does ltr vs rtl evaluation matter between expression all of the same precedence

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't fundamental. As an example, define operator $\star$ as $a \star b = \frac b a$ and check your conjecture again.